# Why is sport in Spanish 'deporte' and not 'esporte'?

Tags: etimología

One would expect that the Spanish word for 'sport' would be *esporte* (as in special => *especial*, spaghetti => *espagueti*, Spain => *España*, etc.). But it's actually *deporte*.

Why does it begin with *de-* and not with *es-*?

Comment: 1) Why assume the words in English and Spanish should relate to each other at all?  2) Why assume Spanish should follow English instead of the other way around? Maybe the English word should be "deports" :)

Comment: I don't think that's a valid reason to expect "sport" to be translated as "esporte" (or any word to be translated in a particular way), because English and Spanish do not share roots (in general). Canonical example: *library*, which is not the same as *librería*. The "method" would be sort of valid if you did this between French, Italian and Spanish, for example, because you have common roots in Latin and Greek.

Comment: @Janoma: library and librería is not a good example for your point, because they _do_ share common roots between English and Spanish. The words do diverge in their meaning and evolution, but not in their roots.

Comment: True. What I wanted to say is that it should not be expected that words that sound similar should have similar meanings, and viceversa.

Comment: "especial" also exists in English. I find this question as senseless as "if oranges are called oranges why lemons are not called yellows?"

Comment: @Janoma: English and Spanish do share roots...they are both Indo-European languages.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In fact both English *sport* and Spanish *deporte* come from Latin *deportāre* / *deportō*.

The Spanish etymology at least as far as the spelling is concerned is quite straightforward. **There never was an *s***.

It's the English etymology that picked up the *s* and lost the *de*. The reason is because English picked up the word from Anglo-Norman, the version of French spoken in England when it was ruled by the Normans. Anglo-Norman had *desporter* as a variant of *deporter* which it had inherited from Old French.

References:

- [English Wiktionary *sport*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sport#Etymology)
- [English Wiktionary *desport*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desport#Anglo-Norman)
- [`etymonline.com` *sport*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sport)

Comment: Bravo, you win!

Answer (score 8):

Bear in mind that the word 'sport' (the current concept, actually) is relatively modern - end of XIX century, and the fashion came from England. At that moment, Spanish speakers had several options to name the new thing:

1. Import the English word: "sport"
2. Adapt it to Spanish : "esport, espor, esporte..."
3. Resurrect/recycle the archaic meaning of the verb "deportar": "to go outside to play some recreative activity", and adapt it to the new meaning, as noun: "deporte"

The first option was widely used at first (there are traces: some clubs and teams in Argentina includes "Sporting" in its name), but eventually the third won.

As pferor's answer mentions, the main  meaning of "deportar" is to deport: expel a person from a country, it comes from de-porta (out-doors), and that relates to the other meaning (the archaic and the new one). That also relates to the English word, which comes from the French (and which includes the 's': desport).

I find it curious that the adaption from the old meaning of "deportar" to "deporte" didn't carry the verb: we don't say "deportar" but "hacer deporte".

Answer (score 5):

Because *deporte* cames from *deportar* which cames from Latin *deportāre*.

> **[deportar](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=deporte).**
>
> (Del lat. *deportāre*).
>
> 1. tr. Desterrar a alguien a un lugar, por lo regular extranjero, y confinarlo allí por razones políticas o como castigo.
> 2. prnl. ant. Descansar, reposar, hacer mansión.
> 3. prnl. ant. Divertirse, recrearse.

Although the main definition of *deporte* is “to practice a physical activity in a game or competition with specific rules”, its second acception means “Recreation, leisure, pleasure, fun or exercise, usually outdoors.” (*Recreación, pasatiempo, placer, diversión o ejercicio físico, por lo común al aire libre.*), and in that case it may be used as a synonym of the third acception of *deportar*.